# Where to validate pagination logic in domain driven design?

Tags: validation, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

In DDD, where should validation logic for pagination queries reside? 
For example, if the service layer receives a query for a collection with parameters that look like (in Go), though feel free to answer in any language:

```
// in one file
package repositories

type Page struct {
   Limit int
   Offset int
}

// Should Page, which is part of the repository 
// layer, have validation behaviour?
func (p *Page) Validate() error {
   if p.Limit > 100 {
      // ...
   }
}

type Repository interface {
  func getCollection(p *Page) (collection, error)
}



// in another file
package service

import "repositories"

type Service struct {
  repository repositories.Repository
}

// service layer
func (s *Service) getCollection(p *repositories.Page) (pages, error) {
    // delegate validation to the repository layer?
    // i.e - p.Validate()

    // or call some kind of validation logic in the service layer
    // i.e - validatePagination(p)

    s.repository.getCollection(p)
}

func validatePagination(p *Page) error {
  if p.Limit > 100 {
    ...
  }
}
```

and I want to enforce a "no `Limit` greater than 100" rule, does this rule belong in the Service layer or is it more of a Repository concern?

At first glance it seems like it should be enforced at the Repository layer, but on second thought, it's not necessarily an actual limitation of the repository itself. It's more of a rule driven by business constraints that belongs on the entity model. However `Page` isn't really a domain entity either, it's more a property of the Repository layer.

To me, this kind of validation logic seems stuck somewhere between being a business rule and a repository concern. Where should the validation logic go?

Comment: I agree with @plalx.  Pagination may be a business rule, in a broad sense, but it is an technical application concern.  Are the business users describing this requirement in a means that is not related to the actual usage?  If so, they are specifically talking about technical implementation details.  I'll provide some details in support of plalx, as a possible additional way to look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red flag for me, is the same one identified by @plalx.  Specifically:

> It's more of a rule driven by business constraints that belongs on the
>   entity model

In all likelihood, one of two things are happening.  The less likely of the two is that the business users are trying to define the technical application the domain model.  Every once in a while, you have a business user who knows enough about technology to try to interject these things, and they should be listened to - as a concern, and not a requirement.  Use cases should not define performance attributes, as those are acceptance criteria of the application, itself.

That leads into the more likely scenario, in that the business user is describing pagination in terms of the user interface.  Again, this is something that should be talked about.  However, this is not a use case, as it applies to the domain.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with limiting dataset sizes.  What is important is how you limit those sizes.  There is an obvious concern that too much data could be pulled back.  For example, if your domain contains tens of thousands of products, you likely do not want all of those products returned.

To address this, you should also look at why you have a scenario that can return too much data in the first place.  When looking at it purely from a repository's perspective, the repository is used simply as a CRUD factory.  If your concern is what a developer could do with a repository, there are other ways to paginate large datasets without bleeding either a technological or application concern into the domain.  If you can safely deduce that the aspect of pagination is something owned by the implementation of the application, there is absolutely nothing wrong with having the pagination code outside of the domain completely, in an application service.  Let the application service perform the heavy lifting of understanding the application's requirement of pagination, interpreting those requirements, and then very specifically telling the domain what it wants.

Instead of having some sort of GetAll() method, considering having a GetById() method that takes an array of identifiers.  Your application service performs a dedicated task of "searching" and determining what the application is expecting to see.  The benefit may not be immediately apparent, but what do you do when you are searching through millions of records?  If you want to considering using something like a Lucene, Endeca, FAST, or similar, do you really need to crack the domain for that?  When, or if, you get to the point where you want to change out a technical detail and you find yourself having to actually touch your domain, to me, that is a rather large problem.  When your domain starts to serve multiple applications, will all of those application share the same application requirements?

The last point is the one that I find hits home the most.  Several years back, I was in the same situation.  Our domain had pagination inside of the repositories, because we had a business user who had enough sway and just enough technical knowledge to be dangerous.  Despite the objections of the team, we were overruled (which is a discussion onto itself).  Ultimately, we were forced to put pagination inside of the domain.  The following year, we started to use the domain within the concept of other application's inside of the business.  The actual business rules never changed, but the way that we searched did - depending on the application.  That left us having to bring up another set of methods to accommodate, with the promise of reconciliation in the future.

That reconciliation came with the fourth application to use the domain, which was for an external third-party to consume, when we finally conveyed the message that these continual changes in the domain could have been avoided by allowing the application to own its own requirements and providing a means to facilitate a specific question - such as "give me these specific products".  The previous approach of "give me twenty products, sorted in this fashion, with a specific offset" in no way described the domain.  Each application determined what a "pagination" ultimately meant to itself and how it wanted to load those results.  Top result, reversing order in the middle of a paged set, etc.  Those were all eliminated because those were moved nearer their actual responsibilities and we empowered the application while still protecting the domain.  We used the service layer as a delineation for what is considered "safe".  Since the service layer acted as a go-between, between the domain and the application, we could reject a request at the service-level if, for example, the application requested more than one hundred results.  This way, the application could not just do whatever it pleased, and the domain was left gleefully oblivious to the technical limitation being applied to the call being made.

Comment: This is an an incredible answer and the real world anecdotes are very helpful. I read it over three times and it clarifies all of my doubts, particularly the 3rd and last paragraphs. I think the lightbulb moment is realizing that pagination is just another way to view data (obvious in retrospect!).

Comment: The application can demand any view of a collection it wants (whether specified as a limit/offset, cursor, set of IDs, etc) but must do so through the service; this does not disturb the domain. It is up to the service not only to determine whether the query will produce a valid view in the context of the application, but to interpret the query and invoke the appropriate logic exposed by the domain.

Comment: The domain does not (should not) concern itself with pagination, which is just a specific view into the domain. As Guillaume31 and plalx also suggest, this is an application or even a presentation level concern. The domain remains independent and does not concern itself with *how* it is being used. The only validation it should perform is on its own invariants.

Comment: Glad we could be of assistance!  You definitely got it down now.  Probably one of the hardest sells that you will have is breaking the perception that having to write a little more code is a bad thing.  Simplicity is great, when it can be achieved.  You can always write less code to get something that works right now.  The goal is always to have something that works right later, as well.  :-)

Comment: Going a CQRS-like approach and by-pass the domain for most queries is something that I always do and it eliminates this issue completely. It forces you to recognize that there are 2 models at stake, a command (domain) and a query model even if you do not go with a full-blown query model (e.g. query from the write DB). I'd strongly recommend this approach @Anchor. You wouldn't even have asked this question if you went that way because the paging would have found it's natural home in the querying services.

Comment: @plalx you make a good point and I’ve been a fan of CQRS since playing around with it in a few toy projects. The only worry is the kind of complexity that can sometimes come with such an architecture and whether or not it would be a premature optimization.

Comment: @Anchor You do not need to have all the artifacts of CQRS such as commands, command bus, exclusive database read model and projections. A very lightweight way of doing it is just to write SQL queries against your write database for queries. That's it, no real objects involved there and you are totally independent of the domain.

Answer (score 5):

> "It's more of a rule driven by business constraints that belongs on
>   the entity model"

These kind of rules generally aren't business rules, they are simply put in place (most likely by developers without business experts involvement) due to technical system limitations (e.g. guarantee the system's stability). They usually find their natural home in the Application layer, but could be placed elsewhere if it's more practical to do so.

On the other hand, if business experts are interested by the resource/cost factor and decide to market this so that customers may pay more to view more at a time then that would become a business rule; something the business really cares about.

In that case the rule checking would certainly not go in the `Repository` because the business rules would get buried in the infrastructure layer. Not only that but the `Repository` is very low-level and may be used in automated scripts or other processes where you would not want these limitations to apply.

Actually, I usually apply some CQRS principles and avoid going through repositories entirely for queries, but that's another story.

Comment: I'm not agreed with your explanation concerning *developers*. I believe that DDD is about expressing the domain *in code*. If there's a general rule that says *don't get more than 100 results at once*, it should be definitively put in the repository. In fact, you would design a base `Repository` class to DRY.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer "If there's a general rule that says" - This is what I'm saying, why would the domain experts care about that? This rule will certainly not come from the experts themselves. Most likely we as developers will go see them and tell them "we have to limit the number of records shown at once to preserve the system's stability". That makes it a technical rule which has nothing to do with the domain at all and therefore doesn't belong there, leaving it to the application layer (or  potentially other ones) to enforce.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer BTW If you consider it a business rule there are better ways to DRY. Just introduce a `Limit` Value Object which enforces the constraint at construction and make your repositories depend on that contract. No inheritance needed there.

Comment: Answer to your #1 comment => BTW I don't take paradigms or design patterns like *dogmas*. Probably is easier and cleaner introducing some limitations in a repository because no operation against the underlying store will bypass the repository layer. And most DI/IoC containers are able to configure same implementation with different values for arbitrary constructor parameters. So I can adapt same repository to enforce certain rules or contracts by configuration.

Comment: Answer to your #2 comment => Yes, you might be right. Anyway, I find defining a basic repository interface and abstract implementation as part of infrastructure layer extremely useful. There's a chance that some operations should behave in some way across the entire solution and all domains. That is, this approach is very DRY when the project grows up.

Comment: Actually, I created a site a year ago called DesignPatternNINJA (http://designpattern.ninja). I both document patterns and anti-patterns, and I compose blog posts. I believe I'm going to write up a new post trying to extensively discuss why repositories should be always considered *domain*, excepting some possible basic contracts and implementations which would go into infrastructure layer.

Answer (score 2):

> At first glance it seems like it should be enforced at the Repository
>   layer, but on second thought, it's not necessarily an actual
>   limitation of the repository itself. It's more of a rule driven by
>   business constraints that belongs on the entity model.

Actually *repositories are still domain*. They're mediators between the domain and data mapping layer. Thereby, you should still consider them as *domain*.

Therefore, a repository interface implementation should enforce domain rules.

In summary, I would ask myself: **do I want to allow non-paginated access to abstracted data by the repository from any domain operation?**. And the answer should be **probably not**, because such domain might own thousands of domain objects, and it would be a suboptimal retrieval trying to get too many domain objects at once, wouldn't be?

### Suggestion

<sup>* *Since I don't know which language is currently using the OP, and I find that programming language doesn't matter on this Q&A, I'll explain a possible approach using C# and the OP can translate it to any programming language*.</sup>

For me, enforcing a *no more than 100 results per query* rule should be a cross-cutting concern. In opposite to what [@plalx has said on his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41636304/411632), I really believe that something that can be expressed in code is the way to go and it's not only an optimization concern, but a rule enforced to the entire solution.

Based on what I've said above, I would design a `Repository` abstract class to provide some common behaviors and rules across the entire solution:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
      IList<T> List(int skip = 0, int take = 0);
      // Other method definitions like Add, Remove, GetById...
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
      protected virtual void EnsureValidPagination(int skip = 0, int take = 0)
      {
           if(take > 100)
           {
                 throw new ArgumentException("take", "Cannot take more than 100 objects at once");
           }
      }

      public IList<T> List(int skip = 0, int take = 0)
      {
           EnsureValidPagination(skip, take);

           return DoList<T>(skip, take);
      }

      protected abstract IList<T> DoList(int skip = 0, int take = 0);

      // Other methods like Add, Remove, GetById...
}
```

Now you would be able to call `EnsureValidPagination` in any implementation of `IRepository<T>` that would also inherit `Repository<T>`, whenever you implement an operation which involves returning object collections.

**If you need to enforce such rule to some specific domain**, you could just design another abstract class deriving some like I've described above, and introduce the whole rule there.

In my case, I always implement a solution-wide *repository* base class and I specialize it on each domain if needed, and I use it as base class to specific domain repository implementations.

### Answering to some @guillaume31 comment/concern on his answer

> I agree that it isn't a domain-specific rule. But Application and
>   Presentation aren't domain either. Repository is probably a bit too
>   sweeping and low-level for me -- what if a command line data utility
>   wants to fetch a vast number of items and still use the same domain
>   and persistence layers as the other applications?

Imagine you've defined a repository interface as follows:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
      IList<Product> List(int skip = 0, int take = 0);
}
```

An interface wouldn't define a limitation on *how many products I can take at once*, but see the following implementation to `IProductRepository`:

```
public class ProductRepository : IRepository
{
     public ProductRepository(int defaultMaxListingResults = -1)
     {
          DefaultMaxListingResults  = defaultMaxListingResults;
     }

     private int DefaultMaxListingResults { get; }

     private void EnsureListingArguments(int skip = 0, int take = 0)
     {
          if(take > DefaultMaxListingResults)
          {
               throw new InvalidOperationException($"This repository can't take more results than {DefaultMaxListingResults} at once");
          }
     }

     public IList<Product> List(int skip = 0, int take = 0)
     {
            EnsureListingArguments(skip, take);
     }
}
```

Who said we need to *harcode* the maximum number of results that can be taken at once? If the same domain is consumed by different application layers I see you wouldn't be able to *inject* different constructor parameters depending on particular requirements by these application layers.

I see same service layer injecting exactly the same repository implementation with different configurations depending on the consumer of the whole domain.

### Not a technical requirement at all

I want to throw my two cents on some consensus made by other answerers, which I believe that are partially right.

The consensus is a limitation like the one required by the OP *is a technical requirement* rather than a *business requirement*.

BTW, it seems like no one has put the focus on the fact that domains can talk to each other. That is, **you don't design your domain and other layers to support the more traditional execution flow: `data <-> data mapping <-> repository <-> service layer <-> application service <-> presentation`** (this is just a sample flow, it might be variants of it).

Domain should be bullet proof in all possible scenarios or use cases on which it'll be consumed or interacted. Hence, you should consider the following scenario: domain interactions.

We shouldn't be less philosophical and more ready to see the real world scenario, and the whole rule can happen in two ways:

1. **The entire project isn't allowed to take more than 100 domain objects at once**.
2. **One or more domains aren't allowed to take more than 100 domain objects at once**.

Some argue that we're talking about a technical requirement, but for me is a domain rule **because it also enforces good coding practices**. *Why?* Because I really think that, at the end of the day, there's no chance that you would want to get an entire domain object collection, **because pagination has many flavors and one is the *infinite scroll pagination*** which can be also be applied to command-line interfaces and simulate the feel of a *get all* operation. So, **force your entire solution to do things right, and avoid *get all* operations**, and probably the domain itself will be implemented differently than when there's no pagination limitation.

BTW, you should consider the following strategy: the domain enforces that you couldn't retrieve more than 100 domain objects, but any other layer on top of it can also define a limit lower than 100: you can't get more than 50 domain objects at once, otherwise the UI would suffer performance issues. This won't break the domain rule because the domain won't cry if you artificially limit what you can get within the range of its rule.

Comment: It would be more useful to discuss what's wrong with my answer rather than getting a stealthy downvote.

Comment: What's wrong is that your answer doesn't focus on DDD. It just offers a technical solution to the problem, but doesn't give any insights to help the OP discover whether or not the rule in his domain shall be seen as a technical/optimization rule or as a true business rule.

Comment: Also, "Actually repositories are still domain" - Their interface (contract) is, not their implementation which belongs to the infrastructure. "Therefore, a repository interface implementation should enforce domain rules". That's a fallacy, the fact that the interface is defined in domain terms doesn't justify burying domain logic in the implementation which is part of the infrastructure layer.

Comment: @plalx About your #1 comment: OP asked about where to put the whole validation **in code**, thus, I gave him a solution with **sample codes**. And my answer provides insights, I give OP reasons to think about where to put that validation.

Comment: @plalx About your #2 comment: I believe you're wrong. What can belong to infrastructure is a generic repository interface, but something like `IProductRepository` is still infrastructure? IMHO, the rest of your argument seems broken just because you define that repository interfaces are an infrastructure thing...

Comment: "your argument seems broken just because you define that repository interfaces are an infrastructure thing..." I think you misread me, because I'm actually stating the opposite. The interface belongs to the domain, but not the implementation. That's the whole foundation of my argument against your statement. Please read my second comment again.

Comment: "I give OP reasons to think about where to put that validation" - If what you are referring to is the paragraph starting with "For me, enforcing a", then without wanting to be disrespectful I feel those are a lot of words without meaning.

Comment: @plalx I'm trying to argue that both interfaces and implementations should go into the domain layer. Probably I'm not alone on this matter, and you're also not alone on your point of view. Just use Google and you'll see that there's no consensus about this.

Comment: @plalx For me, that paragraph has a lot of meaning. Do you mean that it's hard to understand and I should rephrase it, or do you mean that I wrote a paragraph full of good words which make no sense?

Comment: This is a great discussion, though I feel downvotes are unwarranted since there is no consensus on a “correct” way of doing things. 

My first instinct is to agree with @Matías Fidemraizer. Pagination is just a specialized way of retrieving entities, and a `Page` is just a specification defining parameters to achieve that. Since retrieving entities is preeminently the job of the repository, it follows that validating pagination should be a repository behaviour.

Comment: On the other hand, what @plalx is saying makes a lot of sense: repository interfaces should be part of the domain while the actual implementation should be injected in from a higher level. I notice in the example above that enforcement is not defined as part of the `IProductRepository` interface; instead it is part of the `ProductRepository` implementation. By putting validation rules inside the implementation, coupling is introduced between validation rules and transient implementations. Regardless of the implementation, we want certain guarantees about validation behaviours.

Comment: I think what’s tricky here is that there is a disconnect between DDD and real world practicalities. If we were to use pure DDD then repositories should be “dumb”. You put things in them and you take things out with no concept of validation at all. Their Single Responsibility is to abstract away the specific method of persistence. But like @Matías Fidemraizer says, this would result in pulling potentially 1000s of object out of the store even if the end consumer asked for just 10. So already, we do not have an ideal definition of a repository.

Comment: I have to think about this a bit more, but I think an imperfect compromise would be defining rules and specifications in some kind of validator class, and enforcing these rules at the application level.

Comment: @Anchor I'm not sure about your conclusion. Because it'll end up overcomplicating your solution. Double check the part where I answer guillaume31 concerns, and I handle them. If you already use a DI/IoC container, you should really consider this approach. But at the end of the day, it's up to you :)

Comment: @Anchor Now I've double checked some of your comments, where you argue the thing about coupling validation with transient implementations. BTW, no one has said that all domain rules should be hardcoded. If some of them are enabled or mutated based on some higher level configuration, what really define which rules are loaded into the repository is your approach to load them. Thus, there should be nothing wrong with defining that you don't want pages of more than 100 items in the repository implementation.

Comment: @Anchor  At the end of the day, a repository contract isn't about how it must behave but what can potentially do an implementation. The actual behavior of a repository is dictated by concrete domain rules.

Comment: @Anchor Therefore, for me, a limitation on how many items should be returned from a list operation should be on the repository implementation, because the repository can be accessed by many application services, and there's no guarantee about being sure that all application services will inject the same validator with the same ruleset, while all services working with some domain objects will always require the same repository.

Comment: `at the end of the day, a repository contract isn't about how it must behave but what can potentially do an implementation. The actual behavior of a repository is dictated by concrete domain rules.`



@Matías Fidemraizer i’d disagree with this statement. IMHO, contracts are all about behaviour. What you *do* lack guarantees for are how these behaviours are implemented. The only thing that is guaranteed is what the interface method will accept as input and what it will produce as output, nothing else.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer as for the last comment, just as there is no guarantee that services will inject the same validator with the same ruleset, there is similarly no guarantee as to what repository implementation will be injected into the service, correct? What if we create a `CachedProductRepository` and we forget to validate `Limit` in the ctor? The service will hum along just fine without any complaint and we’ll end up paying a massive bandwidth bill.

Comment: @Anchor That's why my proposal is to generalize this validation in an abstract class so it's impossible that you forget to provide that limitation.

Comment: @Anchor About the thing of guarantees... For me a validator is a less important thing than a repository. You can forget to configure a validator, but you'll never forget to configure a repository, because your solution won't work at all :D

Comment: @Anchor BTW, as you've already said, there will be no definitive answer to your concerns. You'll need to decide to go for some subjective solution and experience it yourself.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer fair enough. I do thank you for the detailed response and for sharing your experience in this discussion. I find it all very fascinating!

Comment: @Anchor See my last update. I really believe that other answerers and even you are very UI-oriented, and domain has nothing to do with *who* consumes it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the Application layer, or even Presentation.

Choose Application if you want that rule to hold true for all front ends (web, mobile app, etc.), Presentation if the limit has to do with how much a specific device is able to display on screen at a time.

[Edit for clarification]

Judging by the other answers and comments, we're really talking about **defensive programming to protect performance**.

It cannot be in the Domain layer IMO because it's a programmer-to-programmer thing, not a domain requirement. When you talk to your railway domain expert, do they bring up or care about a maximum number of trains that can be taken out of any set of trains at a time? Probably not. It's not in the Ubiquitous Language.

Infrastructure layer (Repository implementation) is an option but as I said, I find it inconvenient and overly restrictive to control things at such a low level. Matías's proposed implementation of a parameterized Repository is admittedly an elegant solution though, because each application can specify their own maximum, so why not - if you really want to apply a broad sweeping limit on `XRepository.GetAll()` to a whole applicative space.

Comment: BTW I believe that "a limit lower than 100" isn't a domain-specific rule. Thus, it seems like it should be enforced in a repository implementation to spread the rule across the entire solution.

Comment: I agree that it isn't a domain-specific rule. But Application and Presentation aren't domain either. Repository is probably a bit too sweeping and low-level for me -- what if a command line data utility wants to fetch a vast number of items and still use the same domain and persistence layers as the other applications?

Comment: Will you check my last update in my answer, where I try to address your concern, please? We can continue the discussion on my answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm agree about your thoughts in a very philosophical point of view. My point is that we're developing software after all, aren't we? It's all about achieving a solution that may or may not be in accordance with a paradigm or set of design patterns, because our main goal is developing software, and DDD is about software. You know that there're a lot of things in DDD and many other padagims and pattern which are very subjective and I feel that their goal isn't creating a *dogma* but working as a starting point to let us discuss about meaningful things to get to the best solution possible.

Comment: (continuation) If this is our goal, in my case I want to avoid to put some parts of my software in a given place because there's an abstract definition which states that it can't be there. If my solution is more reliable if I impersonate a *tech requirement* as a *domain requirement*, because I avoid repeating myself too much  that way, I believe I did the best decision for my particular project and domains.

Comment: Or, as I've described on my most up-to-date answer, maybe I'm not impersonating a tech requirement, but it's a domain requirement: I want such rule because it enforces good coding practices and, at best, forcing not so big collection pages, the entire domain can end up coded in a very different way than when you think that a global page limit doesn't exist until you get into the app or presentation layer.

Comment: BTW, we should leave our thoughts on this topic here, because I really enjoyed our discussions with you and other answerers. I love discussing about software architecture ;)